# Identifying a Permutation problem vs a Combination problem

Tags: permutations, combinations

I understand that combination is used when the order of something doesn't matter. For the most part I can differentiate between the two. But there are times when I am almost certain something is combination based and it ends up being permutation. This problem for example :

In the Sociology Department there are 8 female faculty members and 9 male faculty members. 
Either 2 female faculty members or 2 male faculty members will be chosen and assigned the following tasks:
play on the departmental co-ed rugby team; team-teach a liberal arts course.
How many different outcomes are possible, assuming that nobody will be assigned more than one task?

My solution was $\binom82$+$\binom92$. The actual solution was the same but with a permutation. I am curious as to how the order matters here. In my mind i'm thinking it does not matter which female or male faculty matters are chosen either way 2 of each faculty will be chosen. Is this the wrong way to assess the problem? Can someone give me a thorough explanation on some key words to look out for to differentiate between the two so that I do not make such careless errors on my exam.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The key is that one of them will play rugby and one will teach liberal arts. The way this connects to "the order matters" is you can imagine that the first faculty member selected will play rugby and the second selected will teach liberal arts.

This is contrast to something where they are, say, selected to be on a committee. Then the committee having teacher $A$ and teacher $B$ on it is the same outcome as the committee having having teacher $B$ and teacher $A$ on it. In this situation you would use combinations.

Note that this is really different from your question. The outcome where teacher $A$ plays rugby and teacher $B$ teaches liberal arts is different from the outcome where teacher $B$ plays rugby and teacher $A$ teaches liberal arts.

Comment: That made sense to me. But when I try to apply it I still cant figure it out completely. For example : In the Economics Department there are 9 faculty members. 3 faculty members will be chosen to serve on a doctoral student's advising committee and 3 other faculty members will be chosen to clean the faculty restrooms. How many different outcomes are possible? Applying your explanation this seems to be permutation based to me. Can you explain the differences between this problem and the one I posted earlier?

Comment: You know, honestly, I never learned the terms "combination" and "permutation" until I joined Math SE, and I feel like I was much better for it. For me it was always just counting. For instance, here you have to choose three from the nine to do the advising, and then three from the remaining six to do the cleaning. That's $$ {9\choose 3}{6\choose 3} = 1680.$$ The fact that the 'order' of the three faculty member on each assignment doesn't matter means you 'use combinations' when choosing the three from the nine and the three from the six.

Comment: If there were a captain and a first mate and a second mate on each of the two teams, you would 'use permutations' and it would be $$ 9p3\times 6p3 = 60480...$$ but again it's better you actually understand the counting behind each procedure rather than how to choose which one of two things to use (which will not work on complex problems). For instance, do you know how I knew to multiply by $36$ to get from the first answer to the second? (I never even calculated a "permuation")

Answer (score 0):

The part that is most important is:

> ...play on the departmental co-ed rugby team; team-teach a liberal arts course.

Because it tells you that there are 2 choices. You can make it more clear by pretending the male and female faculty members line up in separate lines randomly and the first 2 in the line are chosen. The first goes to the departmental co-ed rugby team and then the second the liberal arts course. Then switch the order of the first 2 and see if it makes a difference to who goes where.